# Execute handler as idempotent approach

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I struggle with the following issue:

```yaml
- name: Mount installer iso (Debian)
  become: true
  block:
    - name: Create mnt dir
      ansible.builtin.file:
        path: "/mnt/{{ package }}"
        state: directory
        mode: "0755"
    - name: Mount iso file
      ansible.posix.mount:
        path: "/mnt/{{ package }}"
        src: "tmp/{{ package }}.iso"
        fstype: iso9660
        state: ephemeral
      register: linux_iso_mounted
```

This Task is part of my role for installing a software which is provided via iso. If the mount task was successful but a followup task fails, the iso is still mounted and the task fails next time.

My first suggestion was to use `pre_tasks` and `post_tasks` but they are unavailable for roles as far as I know.

So my second approach is to move the cleanup tasks as handlers and trigger the notify with the `posix.mount`. This should work (not implemented until now) as the handler task get only executed after the finished play (right?).

**Is this best practice or are other approaches better for this scenario?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, there is a simpler approach - `block` provides the [`rescue`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#id7) (that will be executed in case of failure) and `always` (that will be executed in any case) blocks - you can run your cleanup tasks there.

Moreover, AFAIK, [`ansible.posix.mount`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/mount_module.html) module should be idempotent, so you probably won't need the cleanup tasks at all.

Edit: if the failing task is not the `mount` but the following one, the most straightforward solution would be to move it to the same block, and unmount your ISO volume in `rescue` block.

[Handlers](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_handlers.html#controlling-when-handlers-run) will not help in this case. They are running on change, not on failure, and trying to override this behavior, while possible in theory (using an unnecessarily complex logic with custom `failed_when`/`changed_when` on the potentially failing task and `meta: flush_handlers` invocations with `when`), goes against both [KISS principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and [declarative approach](https://www.ansible.com/blog/the-zen-of-ansible/) promoted by Ansible. It would basically result in replicating the same `try-catch-finally` logic that `block-rescue-always` already has out of the box.

Comment: I am not sure, if rescue and always could help here, since I struggled with errors after the block. Maybe a solution if I wrap the follow ups with block as well. Further I only struggled with mount because I used `state: mounted` instead of `ephemeral` which probably caused most of the issues.

Comment: Yes, you can just move that failing task to the same block, and run the `mount` module with `state: unmounted` or `state: absent`. I was a bit confused because you mentioned the following task but didn't include it into your code example. Speaking of handlers, by the way - they won't help in your case as they are running on change, not on failure, and trying to overcome that would result in replicating the same `try-catch-finally` logic that `block-rescue-always` has out of the box.